# NSNotificationCenter makes something with textEdit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, keyboard, nsnotificationcenter

I use NSNotificationCenter for tracking the opening and closing of the keyboard.

In ViewWillAppear

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:@"UIKeyboardWillShowNotification"
                                           object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardwillHide:)
                                             name:@"UIKeyboardWillHideNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

Then

```
- (void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [note userInfo];
    kbSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;


     UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0.0, kbSize.height-50, 0.0);
     [self.tableView setContentInset:contentInsets];
     [self.tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:contentInsets];

    NSInteger lastSectionIndex = [self.tableView numberOfSections] - 1;
    NSInteger lastRowIndex = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSectionIndex] - 1;
    NSIndexPath *pathToLastRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowIndex inSection:lastSectionIndex];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:pathToLastRow atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

    //поднимаем окно ввода
    CGRect frame = footer.frame;
    frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y -kbSize.height+50;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        footer.frame = frame;
    }];
}

- (void) keyboardwillHide:(NSNotification *)note {

     UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0.0, 0, 0.0);
     [self.tableView setContentInset:contentInsets];
     [self.tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:contentInsets];


    CGRect frame = footer.frame;
    frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y +kbSize.height-50;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        footer.frame = frame;
    }];
}
```

And dealloc all

```
-(void) dealloc {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

}

I have one TextEdit on View and button which should sent TextEdit.text to the next controller.

If I will select TextEdit ->set some text->tap button. Then all will be OK.

**BUT**

If I will select TextEdit ->set some text->deselect TextEdit -> **then** tap button (without keyboard).

It will sent to the next controller something which is Not TEXT ...
I tried to nslog it and it write to console  `<UIViewControllerBuiltinTransitionViewAnimator: 0x170241110>`

Button action and segue

```
    //добавить раздел
-(void)addSection:(UIButton*)sender{
    //убираем клаву
    [addTextField resignFirstResponder];

    BOOL test=YES;
    //проверка на совпадение в с существующими категориями
    if (userLists.count>0) {
        for (int i=0; i<[[userLists objectForKey:@"AllTypes"]count]; i++) {
            if ([addTextField.text isEqualToString:[[[userLists objectForKey:@"AllTypes"]objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"name"]]) {
                test=NO;
            }
        }
    }

    if (test) {
        //открываем добавление секций
        AddSectionTableView *vc=[AddSectionTableView new];
        UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:vc];
        [vc setDelegate:self];
        [vc setName:addTextField.text];
        [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
    }else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Ошибка ввода"
                                                       message: @"Категория с таким названием уже существует!"
                                                      delegate: self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Хорошо"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    //очищаем поле ввода
    addTextField.text=@"";
    //закрываем кнопку добавления
    [addButton setEnabled:NO];
}
```

Second ViewControl

name- text that we get from second View Controller

```
 //Загрузка базы данных
    userLists=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:userListsDOCUMENT];

    ////
    NSMutableDictionary *dd=[NSMutableDictionary new];
    [dd setObject:name forKey:@"name"];

    NSMutableDictionary *AllPeople=[NSMutableDictionary new];

    NSMutableArray *myArray=[NSMutableArray new];
    [myArray addObject:@"1"];
    [myArray addObject:@"2"];
    [myArray addObject:@"4"];

    [AllPeople setObject:myArray forKey:@"AllWeather"];
    [dd setObject:AllPeople forKey:@"AllPeople"];
    NSLog(@"%@",name);

    [[userLists objectForKey:@"AllTypes"] addObject:dd];

    //записываем в файл
    [userLists writeToFile:userListsDOCUMENT atomically:YES];

    [self.delegate addTableData];
    ////
```

First ViewController

```
-(void)addTableData{
    //обновляем списки
    userLists=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:userListsDOCUMENT];

    //добавляем в массив
    [ActivTableArrayForMySections addObject:[[userLists objectForKey:@"AllTypes"] lastObject]];

    //добавляем ячейку для ячейки
    [marks2 addObject:@0];

    //перезагружаем таблицу
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    //прокручиваем вниз
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.contentSize.height)];
}
```

UITextFieldDelegate

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField{
    //открытие кнопки добавление , если есть текст
    if (![textField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [addButton setEnabled:YES];
    }else{
        [addButton setEnabled:NO];
    }
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    //убираем клаву по нажатию на done
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

What can it be ?? Help, I can't understand it .

Comment: What do the keyboard notifications have to do with the code that is executed when you press your button? You need to give more info about what happens when this button is pressed.

Comment: @Stonz2 I add this. But I don't think that can help.

Comment: Your question does not make much sense. As @Stonz2 says, the keyboard notifications are not very relevant. You need to post the IBAction code for your button, (or info about a segue you have linked to the button if it's tied to a segue instead of an action.) You should probably also post the definition of your text field (Is it a UITextField? A UITextView? Then you should post the delegate methods you've written to handle the text field/view. (Don't use the term TextEdit. that is the name of the Mac text editor program.)

Comment: @Duncan C I add All What I have.

Comment: What kind of object is addTextField? A UITextField? What about your UITextFieldDelegate methods?

Comment: @Duncan C Yes , addTextField is UITextField. I'll add UITextFieldDelegate now.

Comment: @DuncanC I understand that all problem is in [addTextField resignFirstResponder]; 

What can it be?